# Stale data from TCP Socket worker

Tags: sockets, tcp, celery, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

first off some background.

I'm trying to write a simple web server, based on flask-appbuilder.
This application will have a Socket TCP connection open, and should be accepting an undefined number of requests.

When someone connect with the socket (let say with telnet) , will be able to send his username, and the socket, will be checking whether the user is active or not on the database and return it this value.

In order to kick it off I started looking in some existing solutions, and I found this one [Simple Network UDP Listen in Flask or Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281935/simple-network-udp-listen-in-flask-or-pyramid)
Which is based on a UDP socket, but the concept is quite similar.

The application run, the users can connect to the socket, but whenever they send their user, the value returned is not what the database is set to (enabled or disabled), and I can't get to understand why .

The web application ui is reacting correctly to the database changes.
But the sql query from withing the socket, seems to be returning some sort of old (stale) data , rather than fetching fresh one from the database.

I'll add here some reference code , maybe I'm doing some silly mistake.

Here is how I'm initialising Celery:

```
class FlaskCelery(Celery):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(FlaskCelery, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.patch_task()

        if 'app' in kwargs:
            self.init_app(kwargs['app'])

    def patch_task(self):
        TaskBase = self.Task
        _celery = self

        class ContextTask(TaskBase):
            abstract = True

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if flask.has_app_context():
                    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    with _celery.app.app_context():
                        return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.Task = ContextTask

    def init_app(self, app):
        self.app = app
        print app.config
        self.config_from_object(app.config)

celery = FlaskCelery()
celery.init_app(app)
```

here is the worker code:

```
@celery.task(name='listen_to_tcp', serializer='json', bind=True)
def listen_to_tcp(self):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', app.config['SOCKET_PORT']))
    sock.listen(0)
    while True:

        connection, client_address = sock.accept()

        try:
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(1024)
                data = data.strip()
                if data:
                    qresult = db.session.query(MyUser).filter_by(username=data).one()
                    connection.sendall(qresult.is_active)
                else:
                    break
        finally:
            connection.close()

listen_to_tcp.delay()
```

Thanks to anyone able to help me out wiht this.
Cheers.
L.

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems it all boils down on having:

```
db.session.commit()
```

before doing the query.
Is there anyone able to explain this behaviour ?
Cheers.
L.